# json_encode output invalid as JSON response to datatables?

Tags: php, json, datatables

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) to create a table with information from my database, but am struggling with passing the data to the table with JSON/AJAX as datatables gives me an invalid JSON response error.

What I am doing is taking the result of a query as an object and encoding it as JSON for the datatable to fetch. I seem to be stuck with getting it encoded to JSON.

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM BedrijfskledingT 
                INNER JOIN Bedrijfskleding ON BedrijfskledingT.KledingID = Bedrijfskleding.KledingID 
                INNER JOIN Gebruikers ON BedrijfskledingT.GebruikerID = Gebruikers.GebruikerID";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
            while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt)) {
                var_dump($obj);
            }

            $json = json_encode($obj);
                var_dump ($json);
```

Whether I dump/echo $json or $obj the result remains the same. I tried putting the output of the `json_encoder` through a [JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) and it gives me the following parse error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
object(stdClass) #1 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Below is the output of $json. I narrowed it down to a single row as there's quite a lot.

```
object(stdClass) #1 (23) { ["GebruikerID"]= > int(17)["KledingID"] => string(5)
"KL001" ["Aantal"] => int(2)["Notitie"] => string(10)
"incl. Logo" ["Omschrijving"] => string(5)
"Broek" ["Artikelnr"] => string(14)
"12179-203-0918" ["Prijs"] => string(5)
"50.36" ["Gebruikersnaam"] => string(2)
"CD" ["Voornaam"] => string(4)
"Coen" ["Tussenvoegsel"] => NULL["Achternaam"] => string(10)
"*******" ["Woonplaats"] => NULL["Email"] => string(25)
"*****@*****.nl" ["Functienaam"] => string(14)
"Field Engineer" ["Bedrijf"] => string(6)
"Cruxin" ["Manager"] => NULL["Werkplek"] => NULL["IndienstTreding"] => string(10)
"1999-12-31" ["Beschrijving"] => NULL["CreatedBy"] => NULL["ModifiedBy"] => NULL["DateCreated"] => NULL["DateModified"] => NULL
}
```

Am I not using `json_encode` properly? Would appreciate help!

Here's my datatables javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = json_encode($obj);
var_dump ($json);
```

Should be

```
// Remember `json_encode` only takes in array and not objects
echo json_encode((array)$obj);
```

`json_encode` has the output of `string` there is no need for `var_dump` over there.

Comment: And his while loop has a var_dump in it too.

Comment: @bassxzero i imagine that is only for debugging or something later in his script. There is no json_encode function called there :) . Also usually the case is that people only need one json output in response and not many of them. But anyway if that requires `json encoding` he should be able to see from answer how to use it :D

Comment: I've tried what you have suggested and the output returned is simply "null". What is causing this? Am I unable to encode $obj as JSON so it gives me null?

Comment: Okay here is another problem. `json_encode` takes in array but you are passing in object. let me change my answer to include that part also

Comment: Ummm... What?  `json_encode()` takes _The value being encoded. Can be any type except a resource._